# Horizon import failed (Integer type error?)

Tags: stellar-core, horizon, docker

I configured a custom docker-compose with Postgres, Stellar Core and Horizon as seperate services. Core and Horizon are running and are responsive via HTTP. Stellar-Core is running on Livenet and is returning "Synced!". Unfortunately the Horizon instance seemed to have problems importing data due to a value that is above the int64 range, but I have no idea where to start digging for that.

`import session failed: get failed: sql: Scan error on column index 1: converting driver.Value type []uint8 ("100000000000000000000") to a int64: value out of range" pid=46`

Answer (score 1):

I believe this has been fixed in [`stellar/go#436`](https://github.com/stellar/go/pull/436). Please upgrade to the newest Horizon version that can be found on [Releases](https://github.com/stellar/go/releases/) page.